# How to get SYSTEM_POWER_STATUS using Silverlight 2/3/4?

Tags: silverlight, power-state

I have a Silverlight application running full screen. Is there a way i can display system power status ( basically battery indicator how much is remaining ?  ) using silverlight?

I tried following

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
private static extern long GetSystemPowerStatus(SYSTEM_POWER_STATUS
lpSystemPowerStatus);
```

But got error message -

> Attempt by security transparent method
>   'SilverlightApplication1.MainPage.x()'
>   to call native code through method
>   'SilverlightApplication1.MainPage.GetSystemPowerStatus(SilverlightApplication1.SYSTEM_POWER_STATUS)'
>   failed.  Methods must be security
>   critical or security safe-critical to
>   call native code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Brian Henderson on the MSDN forums](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/123673/278592.aspx):

> Silverlight runs in a sandboxed security environment and does not have access to client API functions. By design, Silverlight is a cross-client, cross-OS (operating system) so does not not have access to native client API methods. Since you are attempting to call specific Win32 API functions, I would recommend you choose to use a Windows OS specific client technology.

Comment: Does out-of-browser help in this case ?

Comment: Silverlight is **still** a cross-platform technology even when it's out of the browser. What exactly will your app do on the Mac? Or on Linux?